# PanGesture Recognizer not working. [Swift]

Tags: swift, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I would like to go back to the previous view by using Pangesture (drag view) but I can’t. I can do function “pan” only on the left edge of the screen, let’s say 5%. The other area of current view the Pangesture function is not working. Is there any way that I can go back to the root view with Pangesture? Please advise. Thank you.

```
    var pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePanGesture:")
    self.mainView.addGestureRecognizer(pan)


  func handlePanGesture(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    var touchLocation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
```

????

```
}
```

Comment: I suggest creating your UIGestureRecognizer via the storyboard, connect it as an IBOutlet and then add a target action to it to handle the actual gesture.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a view controller that uses a UIPanGestureRecognizer setup on the storyboard:

[image]
[image]
(Just one inspector shown for example purposes)

**ViewController:**

```
class PhotoDetaislViewController: UIViewController {

// the connection
@IBOutlet var swipeRight: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

//Swipe navigation
    swipeRight.addTarget(self, action: "swipeRight:") // sets up the swipeRight var

}

func swipeRight(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    // do your navigation here

}
}
```